# Remove item from array react hooks not working properly

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, rendering

Remove item from array work only on last item rendered but item selected deleted from list

```
  const [otherPhones, setOtherPhones] = useState([]);

    {otherPhones.map((item, i) => {
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            ...DefaultStyles.iconContainer,
            marginBottom: hp("1.25%")
          }}
          key={i}
        >
          <PhoneNumberPicker
            placeholder={i18n.t("other_phone")}
            style={{ flex: 10 }}
            countryHint={countryHint}
            onChange={value => {
              _handleOtherPhone(value, i);
            }}
          />
          <IconButton
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            icon="trash-can-outline"
            color={SECONDARY}
            size={SCALE_20}
            onPress={_deleteOtherPhone.bind(this, i)}
          />
        </View>
      );
    })}

  const _deleteOtherPhone = index => {
    const temp = [...otherPhones];
    temp.splice(index, 1);
    setOtherPhones(temp);
  };
```

When i delete PhoneNumberPicker and display only simple property item everything work fine.
PhoneNumberPicker it's a TextInput with some additional component.

Comment: what about using a filter instead of splice? have you tried?

Comment: Yeah yeah for sure i try it too, the element was removed from the array on both cases but the Child component not updated correctly. Thanks for your response by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help someone, i use useRef() react hooks to refer for every rendered Child on the DOM then i use to update them (after deleting selected element) with the new index after removing an item.

Parent element :

```
 const elRefs = useRef([]);
 if (elRefs.current.length !== otherPhones.length) {
    // add or remove refs
    elRefs.current = Array(otherPhones.length)
      .fill()
      .map((_, i) => elRefs.current[i] || createRef());
  }

...

  const _deleteOtherPhone = index => {
  const temp = [...otherPhones];
  temp.splice(index, 1);
  for (let i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
      const element = temp[i];
      elRefs.current[i].current.removeItem(element);
  }
...
}

...
    <PhoneNumberPicker
    placeholder={i18n.t("other_phone")}
    style={{ flex: 10 }}
    ref={elRefs.current[i]}
    countryHint={countryHint}
    onChange={value => {
    _handleOtherPhone(value, i);
     }}
   />
...
```

Child element PhoneNumberPicker :
update phone number :

```
  removeItem(item) {
    this.setState({ phoneNo: item.phoneNumber });
  }
```